# How to start developing Ruby on Rails applications with heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, cloud

What is the best way to get familiar with the heroku environment? What are the first steps? I want to start programming with it next week, using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: "Not a real question". I'm sure there are plenty of guides/screen-casts/tutorials/documentation on the internet.

Comment: Also, note that Heroku is a platform for deploying completed RoR applications. If you aren't familiar with how to develop RoR apps at all, you will first want to learn about that on your local machine, and then move on to deployment later.

Comment: I thought they offer some development features,too.

Comment: You might be thinking of the original incarnation of Heroku that was an online editing platform / IDE for Rails. That's long gone. It's a hosting platform now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very nice thing (among many) about Heroku is that they maintain solid documentation. Specifically for your question, you should start with [Getting Started with Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get started on ruby on rails using Heroku one of the best things you can do is actually work through the Rails tutorial. It is designed and written with Heroku (and Git which you will be using to deploy) in mind. You can check it out at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.

I don't know if you already know Ruby or not, but the tutorial is designed in such a way that you don't actually need to know Ruby to follow it.

Comment: I have a good knowledge of Ruby and was wondering if I have to keep something in mind when using heroku.

Comment: Heroku is a hosting platform that allows you to quickly and easily build databases, worker processes, CDN's, etc. The thing to keep in mind is that with Heroku there is only one way to do that -- "The Heroku Way." As long as your willing to make the trade offs (less freedom for faster development) then there shouldn't be more much of an issue. Just research how Heroku does each piece.